# returning to previous if statements in bash

Tags: macos, bash

Say I've got the following:

```
echo "Would you like to blarg, or flarg?"
read -e ACT

if [ "$ACT" == "blarg" ]
then
echo "Go Blarg."
echo "Possible Blargs are Blah and Flah, or go back to the previous question."
    read -e MARV
fi

if [ "$ACT" == "flarg" ]
then
echo "Go Flarg."
echo "Possible Flargs are Blah and Flah, or go back to the previous question."
    read -e CARVE
fi
    (more if statements following general pattern)
```

I need to know how to do a `back` to go to the previous question (Blah or Flah) from what would be the answer to either `MARV` or `CARVE`, and one to go back to the first one (Flarg or Blarg).

EDIT: I actually need to know how to redefine a variable using `read`. BOY, do I overthink things.

Comment: Your amended question is even less clear than the original.  What do you mean by 'redefine a variable using `read`'?  You can use the same variable in multiple `read` statements.  There are no gotos in Bash, so if you want to go back, you need to use a `while` loop (usually; a `for` or `until` loop might be alternatives), plus appropriate controls (`break` and `continue`, probably). Note you could use: `while echo "…prompt…"; read -e ACT; do …; done` for the loop control, or `read -p "…prompt…" -e ACT`.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean this:

```
while ! [[ "${ACT-}" =~ [bf]larg ]]
do
    read -e ACT
    [...]
done
```

Comment: Not quite, I need to go from the second `if` statement(blah or flah) to the first(blarg or flarg). That would repeat the question of "blah or flah" as opposed to going back to "flarg or blarg".

Comment: There's no `blah` or `flah` anywhere in your code, so I can't possibly know what you mean.

Comment: Just figured the whole thing out. If I use while statements, and then redefine the variable going to be read, it produces what I need. Thank you, and forgive me. Good day.